# How to resolve TypeError after upgrading React-Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have upgraded react-redux in order to use redux with hooks.

So I tried to upgrade to react-redux from version 5 to the latest version (^7.1.3). But then I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
new ConnectedRouter
node_modules/connected-react-router/lib/ConnectedRouter.js:102
   99 | 
  100 | _this.inTimeTravelling = false; // Subscribe to store changes
  101 | 
> 102 | _this.unsubscribe = context.store.subscribe(function () {
      | ^  103 |   // Extract store's location
  104 |   var _toJS = toJS(getIn(context.store.getState(), ['router', 'location'])),
  105 |       pathnameInStore = _toJS.pathname,
```

I tried to upgrade my connected-react-router too but I get then another error.

The versions of some of my packages are:

```
"react": "^16.8.6",
"connected-react-router": "4.5.0",
"react-redux": "^7.1.3",
"react-router": "4.3.1",
"react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
"redux": "^4.0.4",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
```

and here is my `index.js` :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { ConnectedRouter } from "connected-react-router";
import store, { history } from "store";
import "styles/layout.scss";
import App from "App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
       <div>
        <App />
       </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

My `store.js`

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { createBrowserHistory as createHistory } from 'history'
import rootReducer from 'Store/Reducers/rootReducer'


export const history = createHistory()

const initialState = {}
const enhancers = []
const middleware = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)]

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const devToolsExtension = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__

  if (typeof devToolsExtension === 'function') {
    enhancers.push(devToolsExtension())
  }
}

const composedEnhancers = compose(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  ...enhancers
)

export default createStore(
  connectRouter(history)(rootReducer),
  initialState,
  composedEnhancers
)
```

Comment: the store is not correct; you should pass you own store that created with store in redux

Comment: @sinafarhadi what is not correct exactly? i have own store.js file. I updated my question can u check it ?

Comment: Why you didn't update `react` library to latest version?

Comment: I upgrade everything and my problem is solved.